# Help new users ask questions properly

Tags: support, meta, new-users

When a new user is created, there is a lot of help provided to improve the quality of the question. However, as seen on a daily basis, new users have a tendency to bypass the system and ask questions that give us nothing to work with.

[image]

To avoid these types of questions, wouldn't it be smart to force users with less than 30 reputation points to either add a snippet, image or something to describe their problem more, which could lead to less spam and easier understanding of the problem? Why is the current state as it is?

Comment: I would be worried about such a change, a lot of new users simply create an account, ask a question and never log in again. Those are the sort of people who ask bad questions. Those who stay long term tend to ask good questions and would be worried this could put them off using SO. In addition, we have the tools to suggest changes/flag as needed and even comment to point them in the right direction.

Comment: Such feature wouldn't work. As you already saw and understood: they bypass already existing help, like links to the tour, links to the help center and the question wizard. Another hurdle, like requiring a picture or code snippet would also be bypassed when they think they don't need that for whatever reason.

Comment: True makes sense, but the suggestions tend to just explain things that should be clear from the existing help, but I understand your point.

Comment: Yesterday a new user filled up their question text with "kkkkkk" until it passed quality control while apologizing about the messy question because they "didn't have time". Even when user _know_ their question will be messy they still post it... I don't know how we can avoid behaviour like that.

Comment: Love the thought, but unfortunately, we just can't force anyone to perform certain actions, no matter how beneficial to us, or to them, it would be.  Most users are focused on asking their question, and anything that gets in the way of that (FAQs, tours, quality standards, post bans...) are things to be worked around.  That's generally why the question ban exists; we can only do so much to attempt to educate, and after a while, the system will just prevent you from posting again.  Can't make them read, but we can stop them from posting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that not every question *requires* code (though most probably should), nor images, and *requiring* one or both will just lead to users including some garbage to clear the bar. That's already happening with all the existing quality checks in place (notably code-to-text ratio, which frequently leads to users duplicating entire paragraphs to reach the necessary ratio duplicating entire paragraphs to reach the necessary ratio; or *Title-Uniqueness <strike>2</strike> <strike>3</strike> <strike>4</strike>*). You're basically talking about adding yet another indicator to that list, and the efficacy of that is debatable.

What we really need is an AI to judge the quality of a post. … Yeah… [I'll need a research team and five years](https://xkcd.com/1425/).

Comment: Perhaps SO have machine learning running and we don't even know about it just for this problem just waiting to be turned on!

Comment: I'd *love* for that to be the case, but I won't be holding my breath for it.

Comment: Meh, I'll raise....two research teams and 6-8 weeks!

Comment: Isn't judging the quality of a post what the process to feed [the triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) does?

Comment: @Peter Sure, but that’s after the fact. OP is trying for automatic checks before the question is even asked.